# Here's another German aircraft of unknown descent?

Tags: aircraft-identification

A most unusual all-white single-engine [image]pusher tri-plane

Comment: Siemens-Schuckert DDr.I (just use Google Image search) https://lens.google.com/search?ep=gsbubb&hl=en-CA&re=df&p=AbrfA8raPmLx37JEbrXCvYxQzzK9WDAtKCeHrm_fI4y_HqeP7cYS83HqPE8H7EtSM0e11sdTVUYa7p6wqPdV9CPiHJEWJmP6e3tcIsWaON7sNkxgeF6lKnosPV_SeVfuJzolIZ9H8hhAaJve52S20lW-0tALyNZtjJjq2DtvZWsXUltM6363QYXJ07cSVSbFM51h2Uz65ZLHhy_sjA%3D%3D#lns=W251bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsIkVrY0tKRGswWXpReFkySmhMVEppTjJRdE5EYzFaaTA0TjJNeExXSTBOR05sTldGbFlXWXlNeElmYnpKdlNqZGpVRzFWTXpSa1ZVTm1hVWxtYTFwaVJFTmtaM1owT1hab1p3PT0iLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLDEsbnVsbCxbbnVsbCxudWxsLFswLDAsMTAwMDAwLDEwMDAwMF1dXQ==

Comment: I don't get the downwote here...

Comment: @sophit: That picture is the one from the Wikipedia page for that airplane. Takes about 0.5 seconds to find using Google Image Search. "does not show any research effort" seems to apply. (Note: I didn't downvote, but I would understand how someone could consider that insufficient research. Especially since this is the second Wikipedia picture identification request within 70 minutes.)

Answer (score 1):

This is **[Siemens-Schuckert DDr.I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens-Schuckert_DDr.I)**

> a World War I German twin engine, push-pull configuration triplane
> fighter aircraft. Only one was built, crashing on its first flight.

Your picture is used on the Wikipedia page, it's **not too hard to find** with image search!

Here's what happened to it ([source](https://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft30299.htm))

[image: Siemens-Schuckert DDr.I]

Comment: Many thanks - much appreciated.